# do not include any TableA.ID where TableB.Number = 27

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, where-clause

I have 2 tables.

```
TableA         Table2
------         -------
ID             Number
```

ID is the parent, meaning each TableA.ID can have more than 1 `Number`

Example

```
TableA.ID     Table2.Number
---------     -------------
 123456           27
 123456           13
 123456            1
 123456           111
 222222            32
 222222            93
 333333            27
 333333            44
 443333            27
 443334            66
 443334            22
 443336            27
```

If when Number is 27, then do not query any ID

**output should be**

```
TableA.ID     Table2.Number
---------     -------------
 222222            32
 222222            93
 443334            66
 443334            22
```

Thanks

Comment: How these tables are bound? Do they have any relationships?

Comment: sorry the common between them is `TableA.ID = TableB.ID`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this (assumes that table2 has a column with tableA.id)

```
select tablea.id,table2.number
from tablea join table2 on tablea.id = table2.a_id
where tablea.id NOT IN 
    (select tablea.id from tablea join table2 on tablea.id = table2.a_id
     Where table2.Number = 27)
order by tablea.id,table2.Number
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with a simple `EXISTS`, like this:

```
SELECT
    a.ID, b.Number
FROM
    TableA a
JOIN TableB b ON a.ID=b.ID
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT * FROM TableB x WHERE x.ID=a.ID AND x.Number=27
)
```

The `EXISTS` statement has a subquery referencing `TableB` again. Note that it uses a different alias (namely, `x` instead of `b`).

Comment: sorry but it still showed me, ID's with `27` BWS's answer worked becuase he had joins in internal/sub query also.

Comment: @user206168 BWS's query has a join because it needs to bring `a.ID`. This query does not have a join because it is not necessary. I'm sure this has to do with converting from this skeletal query to a real one: this approach should work absolutely fine.

Comment: @user206168 ...and it works absolutely fine - [demo on sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/659e7/1).

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work. I dont think I made a mistake in converting to real query. I double checked it.